# How to hide the div and make it visible again after some interval while using jquery cycle plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fade show of images and on top i have slide show of another div with description using jquery cycle plugin. Both will happen simultaneously.so that description match the image.

But I want description div to come in from left after image comes and go back like toggle effect before image changes.

Code used is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 6000, 
            delay:  -2000
    });
 $('.slideshowtext').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight',
        timeout: 6000, 
            delay:  -2000
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slideshowtext').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollRight',
    timeout: 6000, 
    delay:  -2000,
    before: slideOut,
    after: slideIn
});

function slideIn() {
  $('.slideshowtext').animate({left: '- [width of the slideshow] px'}, 100);
}

function slideOut() {
  $('.slideshowtext').animate({left: 0}, 100);
}
```

Wrap '.slideshowtext' so that it's overflow to the left will be hidden. Alternatively,have a look at the [s3 slider](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html).